# How to define constants in linux

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

So I am working on my apache config files and am recreating multiple server instances and having to write the same code many times over. I see stuff like this:

```
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

In the default config files, and I would like to use predefined variables in the same manner.

I would like to do something like:

```
ServerName dev.${DEVELOPER_NAME}.admin.mysite.com
```

So I am wondering where something like APACHE_LOG_DIR is defined, and if it's possible to define my own variable in the same location?

Sincere thanks for any help. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: shoot! I meant to ask this is server fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ubuntu these variables are defined in:

```
/etc/apache2/envvars
```

Comment: Thanks! I meant to ask this in server fault. Thanks for the response though.